# 400 bad request for ajax call with GET request parameter passed to controller in spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, drop-down-menu

i'm showing a drop down list in a page based on the selection i have  to show dependent drop down by passing the selected value in drop down list to the controller and return json data as response.please find below code and help me for resolving this .

Please find below ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    contentType : "application/json",
                     url : "${home}getOPList",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){
               //    var str = JSON.stringify(response);
                   var operatorList;
              //         alert("yes");
              //         alert(str);

                       for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ )
                       {
                         console.log(response[i].listOfOperators);
                         operatorList +="<option value =' "
                         + response[i].sno +
                         " '>"
                         + response[i].listOfOperators +
                         "</option>"

                       }
                       $('#opList').html(operatorList);

                },

                    error: function(){
                     alert('Error while request..');
                    }
                   });
          $("#opList").change(function(){
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  dataType : 'json',
                  contentType : "application/json",
                   url : "${home}partnerDetails?operator =" +opList,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(response){
             //    var str = JSON.stringify(response);
                 var partnerList;
                    alert("yes");
                    alert("oplist " + opList);

                     for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ )
                     {
                       console.log(response[i].campaignName);
                      partnerList +="<option value =' "
                       + response[i].sno +
                       " '>"
                       + response[i].campaignName +
                       "</option>"

                     }
                     $('#ptList').html(partnerList);

              },

                  error: function(){
                   alert('Error while request in partners..');
                  }
                 });

          });

  });




</script>
```

above is the ajax code and when the code gest executed it is directly showing " Error while request in partners.. ".in console it says it is a bad request with 400 response code for the below url.

```
http://localhost/Promotions/partnerDetails
```

please suggest on this

Comment: bad request mostly throws when there is an issue with the parameters format or their encoding. Also, check if the content type is correct and as per your server content type.

Comment: @Jayant , should i change the content type for the request

Comment: it depends what content type you have set in your controller